# How can my website tell safari it's ok to save passwords?

Tags: safari

When I logged into my website in safari, I got the following message:

> safari will not save your password because MyWebsite requested passwords not be
>   saved

What meta tag/value do I need on my site to tell Safari it's ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you don't have `autocomplete=off` in any of the forms.  This is the primary way that a website can tell a browser not to save passwords.  By default, if the website doesn't have anything, the browser will be happy to save passwords, so odds are that your website contains something like that somewhere.

Comment: I don't think browsers should respect these kinds of settings in the first place, it should always be possible to copy/paste and automatically fill stuff in